# Odoo integration with Mobile applications

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, odoo-12

I have a web application in Odoo. Need to Implement the same in the mobile application. Is it API's available for developing a mobile app or need to install any plugins to develop applications?

I'm in new to odoo development with the mobile application so kindly share your knowledge with us.

Thanks in Advance.